# alternative (and usage-specific) word for a "condition clause" when speaking of conditional clauses

Tags: single-word-requests, conditionals

Is there any grammar-nerdy term that describes the *condition clause* of a conditional sentence, in terms of its syntactical interrelation to the so-called *consequence*?

Example sentence (based on the sample conditional sentence from WIkipedia
*If it rains, the picnic will be cancelled*):

> "If it rains" is the ________ of "the pic-nic will be cancelled".

Comment: While not used in precisely this way within the field of linguistics, "antecedent" may work for general audiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the word [*protasis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protasis), which is the "if" or "unless" part of a conditional pair.

And the other part, the "then" part, is the *apodosis*.  It doesn’t matter the order.

[Wikipedia writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence):

> The full conditional sentence (one which expresses the condition as well as its consequences) therefore contains two clauses: the dependent clause expressing the condition, called the ***protasis***; and the main clause expressing the consequence, called the ***apodosis***.

Comment: I guess this is the right answer. I had actually been through that Wikipedia-article, but I asked the question anyway, in case there might be some hardcore linguistic term describing *protasis* and *apodosis* in terms of how they relate to each other; not what function they serve within the sentence as a whole... It's as though we're speaking of two brothers (out of 2), calling them "firstborn" and "last-born", whereas, in reference to each other, they're just a "big / baby brother", respectively. I understand it's a friggin' subtle niche of a nuance in meaning. There's probably no such word.

Answer (score 0):

"If it rains" is the **subordinate** clause of "the pic-nic will be cancelled".

> **[Subordinate clause](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subordinate+clause)** is  a clause in a complex sentence that cannot stand alone as a complete sentence